# Access to Sitecore's Update Installation Wizard

Tags: iis, sitecore

I'm trying to upgrade Sitecore version, but I can't get access to  Update Installation Wizard page by following url:
[site name]/sitecore/admin/updateinstallationwizard.aspx

> "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

I have found following note regarding the Wizard:

> "Make sure that IIS is configured to allow access to the /sitecore/admin folder. "

I have provided full access to this folder for appropriate user, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Try to access sitecore login page first (`/sitecore/login`).

Comment: @MarekMusielak it works fine.

Comment: Have you logged in? Can you access UIW when you're logged in?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, Yes, I have. But I cannot access UIW

Comment: Try to open `/sitecore/shell` page. Click on the Sitecore start button and check if you see `Development tools` > `Installation Wizard` there.

Comment: @MarekMusielak, yes, I can see it. But actually it's not the same thing as UIW. I'm trying to upgrade Sitecore version(not install package, question is edited), so I need to get access to `/sitecore/admin/updateinstallationwizard.aspx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Here is solution:

1. Find your site in IIS, move to [site]/sitecore/admin folder in tree.
2. Click on "admin" folder and double click on "Authentication" menu.
3. Enable "Anonymous Authentication".